# What exactly made room 1408 act the way it did?

Tags: 1408

In many films based on Steven King novels, there is an explanation of why stuff exists or is happening. But in [*1408* (2007)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0450385/) I've never got an explanation, why the room is cursed exactly, and what makes it evil.

I do know that the room mainly plays with your mind, so you think that all of this is happening, but in reality it's not (except for some things, like Mike's daughter). I still have no idea, what being plays with your mind.

Comment: No I do meant the movie

Comment: I’m assuming you already know the room is on the 13th floor and the digits of the room number add up to 13? Also I don’t think the Overlook Hotel is explained in the movie version of *The Shining*. Or the titular Pet Semetary.

Answer (score 2):

The prologue of King's original story states (not verbatim, this was taken from the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1408_(short_story)) page):

> After his ordeal, Enslin gives up writing altogether. He has acquired
> various physical and psychological problems stemming from his brief
> stay in the room. He notes to himself (as Olin expressed earlier) that
> there are no ghosts in 1408, because ghosts were once merely humans,
> while the **entity he encountered was horrifically inhuman**. In the end,
> Enslin sleeps with his lights on, has removed all his house's phones,
> and always draws the curtains before dark; he cannot stand the shade
> of yellow-orange at sunset that reminds him of the light inside Room
> 1408.

The director shot 3 separate endings, but ultimately none of them really reflected King's ending.

Answer (score 0):

He is dead and in purgatory that is why 1408 acts the way it does. What Mike did while alive put him in 1408. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purgatory

Comment: What evidence is there to support this conclusion? It'll help OP understand if you explain it more completely.